# Modifying Local Files Using HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there *any* way I can use HTML5 and JavaScript to modify a file on my system? I'm OK with running Chrome or Firefox with specific options or opening permissions in some other way.

Ideally I would like test this by having my browser rename a file on my desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write local file with jQuery or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090747/write-local-file-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: It would be sad, but acceptable =]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this, this link details some of the available functionality:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Just remember, it's not supported in the major browsers yet, and it's likely when it is many of your visitors will not upgrade for quite some time.

Comment: It looks like this only gives you access to a sandboxed filesystem

Comment: Here's some text from the link: It's important to remember that this file system is sandboxed, meaning one web app cannot access another app's files. This also means you cannot read/write files to an arbitrary folder on the user's hard drive (for example My Pictures, My Documents, etc.).

Comment: @Kirk: That's actually a Good Thing. Would you like just any ol' webpage to access your documents? Like, your personal data? I wouldn't, for one.

Comment: @Piskvor For my particular use case I'd like it to have access to approved directories in the file system

Comment: Cool side note: Google Chrome is building an in browser editor.  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/code-editor-app

Answer (score 3):

No, as this would be a security vulnerability. As pointed out there are sandboxed file systems, or local database storage in HTML5, but not access to the whole file system.

You could achieve it with a certified Java applet, if you really wanted to achieve it through the browser. To be honest the browser is not the best place to be trying such things.

Comment: Java applets are no longer supported, so I would use the [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) to modify local files instead.

Answer (score -1):

[VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript#Additional_Functionality) should be appropriate in your case. You will have to lower your internet zone security level though.
Once it's done just use `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and its [MoveFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That's not html, its proprietary internet explorer trash

Comment: @Sevin7 check [kirk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457041/modifying-local-files-using-html5-and-javascript/6460493#comment7587715_6457041)

Comment: internet explorer tr... treasure! :straight-face:

Comment: Which is no longer supported by anyone, not even MS