# can we rename/write to local files in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying Local Files Using HTML5 and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457041/modifying-local-files-using-html5-and-javascript)

I know we can read a local file that has been selected by the user, but is there the ability to rename or write to local files in javascript?

Comment: You can write data to a file and make the browser download that, but that's all sandboxed. You cannot modify any file/directory outside that sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to natively write the filesystem in Javascript, for obvious security reasons.

However, if you **must**, there is an ActiveX object (Only in IE). It's `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

You will find the documentation about that beast [on the msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: no actually you can read local files with javascript only.. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: This is not true with HTML5. See [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader)

Comment: I didn't knew that, interesting ! I'll edit.