# Modify an existing file using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a simple client-side text editor using HTML5 and Javascript. Is it possible to overwrite the contents of an existing text file using HTML5? I know that the HTML File API makes it possible to read the contents of a file, but I haven't yet found a way to modify or overwrite an existing file.

Comment: Depends, where's the file located?

Comment: I'd like to prompt the user to select a file to open, and then modify and overwrite the file.

Comment: Judging by that comment, you don't care where the file is saved, as long as it's saved on prompt. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to select a file to open, and then modify the contents of the file.

Comment: Do you mind if you get two different prompts: One for reading and one for saving?

Comment: That would be an acceptable solution, as long as it can overwrite the original file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14877/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-rob-w)

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457041/modifying-local-files-using-html5-and-javascript

Comment: That is a **virtual** filesystem. For more information, see [tagwiki of html5-filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-filesystem/info) and [Where is the filesystem in html5 stored on the real file system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719816/where-is-the-filesystem-in-html5-stored-on-the-real-file-system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Prompt to open

To read a file, use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) API ([examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)):

#### Prompt to save

To save the file, create an URL using [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) (the blob is constructed via the `FileReader` API, with `type` `application/octet-stream`), or using a data-URI ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473992/938089)).

Comment: riiiight, but this will only work offline-- which if I gather is pretty  much not useful for a website.

Comment: @FlavorScape Hang on, do you want the **client** to **browse on the server** using pure client-side JavaScript? If yes, that's not possible, because **the client can't browse/modify server-side files without a server-side implementation.** The methods suggested by my answer allows a user to select an accessible file from **their computer**, do some magic within the web page, then save the file **on their computer**.

Comment: oh ok-- i guess that's not a requirement. i just assumed that since the  OP used the word "client-side" that there was a "server-side" somewhere

Comment: @FlavorScape Oops, I've mistaken you for the OP, sorry :p

Comment: @Rob W Is it possible to overwrite (instead of duplicating) a file using the method you described?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Only if the user selects the same file. Remember, you cannot directly access the user's filesystem. My method only works if the user allows it (which makes sense).