# Writing file to desktop using HTML5 FileSystem API

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I'm playing around a bit with the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

I've found a lot of examples where you generate a download link and let the user download the file the "browser way".

I would like to know two things:

1. Is there any way to write the ajax result in the fiddle as a file directly to the disk (without any type of prompt). Like to the user's desktop for example.
2. Is blob the most suitable format for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/FBGDe/

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
        var img = document.getElementById('img');
        var url = window.URL = window.webkitURL;
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth
                                                       /NASAEarth-01.jpg');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: "Without any prompt". That would be a serious security issue.

Comment: you can use http://danml.com/js/download.js to save a named file to the downloads folder, without prompt. if you try to download a bunch of files, chrome will ask for approval once per session.

Comment: @11684 I think that you're able to delete files without a prompt with this API. I'd say that's an even bigger security issue in this context

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I'll look in to that

Comment: @Johan, no, because with this API you can only delete files your website put there in the first place.

Comment: Related post - [HTML5 offline storage. File storage? Directories and filesystem API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3936736/465053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, writing to regular files is not currently possible (despite the accepted answer [Modifying Local Files Using HTML5 and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457041/modifying-local-files-using-html5-and-javascript)).

You can only write to the sandboxed filesystem.

FYI, you can do this in a Chrome Packaged App: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html But even then the user must at least choose the file first. Writing to any file would be a serious security hole.

What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: what about <A download> ?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for a late comment. I would like the user to mark a bunch of files > choose a folder > press download and let the browser download them simultaneously. But I guess it's easier to just zip them serverside and download it the regular way.

Comment: Just to elaborate, I don't want to write to an existing file, I want to create a new file. But I suppose that's what you are referring to?

Comment: @Johan, you will have to zip. And the same restrictions apply whether new files or existing files.

Comment: @PaulDraper, this is an old topic, but the problem I would be trying to solve here is a JavaScript based app, which needs to create dummy SQL data on the client side. Say, a CSv file with 10000 dummy names. To save the user from downloading a big file over the internet, I am trying to get it created at the client side via javascript.

Answer (score 14):

Please note that Filesystem API is no longer part of the standard's specification, as specified at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/

EDIT:
Quoting the specification in case the link changes:
"File API: Directories and System
W3C Working Group Note 24 April 2014

**Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation.**"

(This does not relate to the question directly, but it is essential to know not to use the FileSystem API further.)

Another link:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

"In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered dead. Other browsers have showed little interest in implementing it."

Comment: Ok, I will add details, not just the link, henceforth. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly same [end for Web SQL Databases](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/220254/236257) as well which got deprecated. For offline web applications, I believe [Indexed DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) are the remaining options then.