# Using JavaScript to store a file to a local machine (Downloading)

Tags: javascript, download, local-storage

I want to store a file to a local machine.

For HTML5, we can use `cookies` and `local storage` to store data to a local machine. 
Local storage uses `key-value` pairs (`json`) to store data.
However, I want to save data in a different format, in XML for example.

On websites such as convertonlinefree.com, when a file has been converted, the file will automatically begin downloading.

So, I am considering a way to do this:
When the user clicks a button, the XML file would automatically be downloaded. Is this possible? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: Is has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744155/writing-file-to-desktop-using-html5-filesystem-api

Comment: using http://danml.com/js/download.js, it's just download(strXmlData, "myxmlfile1.xml", "text/xml");  using dataURL alone might not trigger a download of XML since some browsers display the document...

Comment: Thanks, I find this in discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744155/writing-file-to-desktop-using-html5-filesystem-api

Comment: http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html is also a very good one

Comment: @yongnan: yeah, downloadify is good for older browsers with flash. It is a bit stale though, and doesn't support newer devices/features/formats as well as my script (not that i'm biased).

Comment: @dandavis thanks, It seems download.js is a good one(easy to use).

Comment: It seems download.js have some problem in FireFox

Answer (score 2):

You can create invisible element, such as `a` and emulate click on it, to download a file, [check my codepen](http://codepen.io/nirth/pen/BksoG) for demo.

The important part is this:

```
var text = xmlContent.value;
// Create element.
a = document.createElement('a');
// Attach href attribute with value of your file.
a.setAttribute("href", "data:application/xml;charset=utf-8," + text);
// HTML5 property, to force browser to download it.
a.setAttribute("download", "my.xml");
a.click();
```

Optionally you can replace `application/xml` part with intentionally incorrect MIME type, to force browser to download file instead of trying to display it.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to use is [Data_URI_scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which basically means you have to base64 encode your file to download it.

So something like this should work:

```
window.location = 'data:application/xml;base64,'+ btoa("<xml>data in the file</xml>")
```

Comment: you should make that a weirdo mime type to force a download, otherwise it might just show up...