# How can I read/write local files directly from a webpage (html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, client-side-scripting

I need to read a local log for an application that my colleagues use. Then use the information in the local log at a central system to keep track of their activities. Need to have a background application/webpage that would copy over the local log to a network drive that is already mapped to every client. Once the data is on the network drive, I have a cron that collates and displays the tracking.

Unfortunately, we cannot deploy a web-server for server-side scripting to achieve this.
I've tried using Javascript but doesn't seem to help as data from the local file cannot be copied over to the network drive. So, need a direct access option for read/write local text/log files.
I'm currently using automation software for this, but it is slowing things down... Hence need a web-based approach for this.

Can this be done via Javascript/jQuery/AJAX without any server side scripting ?

As suggested, the question "Writing file to desktop using HTML5 FileSystem API" does not work as it allows storing the file only on the Sandboxed Filesystem of which is on the local drive for every user and hence it does not fulfill my purpose as I need the files to be saved on a network drive already mapped to every client system.

Comment: Local files are intrinsically not web based.

Comment: The suggested duplicate post for a similar situation is not helpful as it can store files on Sandboxed FileSystem on the local drive of the user whereas, I require the file to be stored on a network drive instead.

Comment: It is helpful because it does address storing files on network drives too. I'll quote the relevant section with additional boldness: *You can **only** write to the sandboxed filesystem*

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744155/writing-file-to-desktop-using-html5-filesystem-api), the browser cannot currently write to files directly. You would need to implement the file writing on your server side.

Comment: Is there any other way apart from a browser which will have a light footprint and runs in the background?