# Read Write Overwrite external files with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local

I wanted to know if there is any way to read write and overwrite external files using javascript or jquery or just another way to work with local data for a html/javascript app?

Not a database just a file like xml or anything else suitable for the task!

Comment: When you say external, do you mean external to the web app, or the server, or ...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write local file with jQuery or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090747/write-local-file-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Im considering to write a app for Windows 8 Metro UI but dont really want to use the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData i want to use a file withing the app that can be read and written for keeping the score for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your needs and requirements for this project I would check out local storage (HTML5). Your can read more about it at http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "XMLFile/CRF_STRUCT_EXTRACT_SUPPORT.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: xmlParser
                });  

});


   function xmlParser(xml) {

// do anything with xml file here.

  }
```