# Is it possible to write a file in a web-application?

Tags: web-applications, dart, dart-html, dart-io

I want to make an entirely client-side text editor. Unfortunately, [dart:io doesn't work client-side](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1324). I want to save text the user has typed to a file on the his machine. He can have full control of where it saves or whatever hoops I have to jump through for it to be considered safe. Is it possible to write a file to his machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this equivalent answer for JavaScript:

[Write local file with jQuery or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090747/write-local-file-with-jquery-or-javascript)

> The web platform is specifically designed to prevent sites from writing arbitrary data to client machines.

This is to protect your machine.

One way that I have seen this worked around is to use something like dropbox or google drive api, so that your app "edits" a file on dropbox or gdrive, which is then synced onto your local disk by the dropbox or gdrive client.   Eg: [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg)

---

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML5 and LocalStorage. It's a persistent storage, but can only be accessed by the browser.

If you want the user to be able to open the file outside the browser, just make the "save" button a download action.

Comment: Can the user save it as an ASCII file on their machine once it's in local storage? I think I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What ilanco was referring to: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download


And a demo: https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html